# How to use APSW with Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, apsw

I have a sqlite3 database but the database is only getting updated when I restart the Flask server.

I think it is because I don't tell Flask that it is a database. So I started using SQLAlchemy and set

```
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

but SQLAlchemy uses pysqlite2 and pysqlite2 will not work on my computer.

Is there a way to use APSW (another python sqlite3 wrapper) with SQLALchemy?

Or is there a way to tell flask to use my database without SQLAlchemy?

or is my problem of the database not updating fixed another way?

Answer (score -1):

Just use this flask tutorial. It uses sqlite and there is no use of sqlalchemy.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/views/#tutorial-views
I don't see them doing anything special, my database won't update until I restart he webserver

Comment: ok. then please post your code so that we can see where the issue is.

Comment: This does not demonstrate using `apsw` with Flask or at all. Even if it did, this violates the principle of not simply posting links but extracting their relevant content. To be fair, I suppose OP asked several questions and this arguably might be related to answering one of them.